helm notation for ribosyl in a siRNA
I need the helm notation for the compounds in this patent by Dicerna: WO2023220351A1.
The chemical modifications, defined on page 141, are all like 5'rXmXrXmXrXrXrXrXrXrXrXrXrXmXrXmXrXrXrXrXrXrXrXXXX 3', where the X are to be replaced by the base. without prefix is a nucleotide, with an m is an m-2'-OMe modified nucleotide. The helmet notations would be r{X}P and [m]{X}P in these cases.
I don't get the rX. The patent says it's a r- ribosyl modified nucleotide, but I don't know what is this, and don't find any reference.
Which is the helm for the r prefix? Any other tip (a better name for instance) would be very useful too.
